# Emacs doesn't understand where the windows are?

Tags: window, navigation

This has occurred several times now. I will have an Emacs session (24.5.1, OSX UI version installed via homebrew) running for a while when suddenly it no longer seems to understand how to navigate between visible windows.

- `other_window` will switch from left-most to right-most window, but not back
- `windmove-right` will work but `windmove-left` will say "No window left from selected window" when obviously there is

Mouse-clicking in a visible window works fine.

Any ideas what is going on? I see no other error messages displayed anywhere. Restarting emacs restores correct behavior until it breaks again later.

Comment: It would help if you can find a step-by-step instruction on how reproduce the problem.

Comment: If a window has the `no-other-window` parameter set, then it cannot be selected by the commands you mentioned. It also causes the same error messages you described. However, it's really hard to know without some more details or a reproduction recipe as @Lindydancer wrote.

Comment: I did not know about `no-other-window`, but found that it was set in some places but not others. Now I have something to investigate, thanks. I haven't come up with a way to reproduce this on demand yet, it's random. I wonder if there is some command that is setting `no-other-window` when I don't expect it.

Comment: @jmay window parameters are set by the `set-window-parameter`. You can try adding an advice to that function to conditionally print a backtrace (or something) when `set-window-parameter` is called